# IF/IFS Formula in excel is resulting in "formula parse error"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

What I was hoping to do was to the First check if there is any value in P3, if not then the S3 would just read blank. If there was a value, it would check to see if K3 is between $0 and $19.99, if it is, multiply K3 by 1.11. If K3 is greater than $19.99 then multiply K3 by 1.27. And last but not least if P3 reads "x" then S3 would also read "x"

I'm new to excel formulas and google sheets formulas, but I tried my best to make it work and cannot seem to figure it out.

I attached an image of the sheet and it's showing the formula too.
[image: Image of the google sheet]

Comment: for me, the issue was that I was wrapping my strings in single (`'`), not double (`"`) quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF(P3="x","x",IF(P3>0,IF(P3<19.99,P3*1.11,P3*1.27),""))
```

Notes:

1. By checking if `P3>0` you know already that it is greater zero and don't need to check again in your formula.
2. `If` formulas work sequentially. So, if the first part evaluates to `True` then the last bit is automatically ignored. Hence, you don't need to verify with the second `If` whether `P3>=19.99`. Since the first part (where `P3<10.99` was checked) did not occur and since `P3>0` has been already checked `P3>=19.99` must be `True`.
3. If you want to check for several things at the same time then you'd use `=IF(AND(P3>0,P3<19.99);P3*1.11;P3*1.27)`